# django deployment using wsgi, on local machine

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to learn how to deploy with mod_wsgi.  I'm using django 1.4 with a small app running in virtualenv

Here are my apache2.conf code changes (ubuntu):

```
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/
# jcg 9/18/2012
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/jgoldstick/code/learn/myapp/wsgi.py
#WSGIPythonPath /home/jgoldstick/code/learn/myapp
WSGIPythonPath /home/jgoldstick/code/learn/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages

<Directory /home/jgoldstick/code/learn/myapp>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

I am getting 404 pages when I access the site.  I am using the standard wsgi.py script that django produces.

what am I missing

Update to be more complete:
Here is my wsgi.py file in myapp/myapp
I added the appends as per first answer.

I am assuming in that answer that wsdl.py really meant wsgi.py.

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append('/home/jgoldstick/code/learn')
sys.path.append('/home/jgoldstick/code/learn/myapp')


os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")

# This application object is used by any WSGI server configured to use this
# file. This includes Django's development server, if the WSGI_APPLICATION
# setting points here.
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

# Apply WSGI middleware here.
# from helloworld.wsgi import HelloWorldApplication
# application = HelloWorldApplication(application)
```

I changed apache2.conf (which I believe is same as httpd.conf for ubuntu configuration) to:

## https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

```
# jcg 9/18/2012
Alias /media/ /home/jgoldstick/code/learn/media/

<Directory /home/jgoldstick/code/learn/media>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/jgoldstick/code/learn/myapp/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/jgoldstick/code/learn/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages

<Directory /home/jgoldstick/code/learn/myapp>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I restarted apache
But I still get 404 when I go to my app

Comment: Please see updates in original question as per WBAR comments below

Comment: It ends up I had bad paths.  On this machine my home is jcg not jgoldstick (duh!).  So WBAR's answer is essential correct for future people with this issue except he calls the first file wsdl.py and i call it wsgi.py.  Then below he refers to it as django.wsgi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wsdl.py:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/home/jgoldstick/code/learn')
sys.path.append('/home/jgoldstick/code/learn/myapp')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

And httpd.conf should look like:

```
Alias /media/ /home/jgoldstick/code/learn/media/

<Directory /home/jgoldstick/code/learn/media>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/jgoldstick/code/learn/myapp/django.wsgi
WSGIPythonPath /home/jgoldstick/code/learn/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages

<Directory /home/jgoldstick/code/learn/myapp>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

If `django.wsgi` is located in `/home/jgoldstick/code/learn/myapp/myapp/django.wsgi` please add `/myapp` everywhere.

The same configuration as `/media/` directory shoud have `static` and remember to execute `./manage.py collectstatic`

Please refer to [Documentation Django-modWSGI](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)